# Is it possible to put variable name "aliases" in TypeScript interfaces?

Tags: json, typescript, interface

I'm writing TypeScript code that fetches JSON from an API. The JSON I receive back has single-letter variable names, and I would prefer them to be more descriptive in my development code.

I then wonder, is it possible to "alias" the variable names in my code, and then have the TypeScript compiler change them to their real names for use in the production code?

What I get from the API is something like this:

```
{
    "a": 10,
    "b": 90,
    "c": "bar"
}
```

And what I would like to do in my interface is something like this:

```
interface Fruits {
    a alias apple: number,
    b alias banana: number,
    c alias cherry: string
}
```

So I then could do this:

```
var fruits: Fruits = fetch("http://foo.bar/fruits.json");

fruits.apple = 50;
```

And have it compile to:

```
var fruits = fetch("http://foo.bar/fruits.json");

fruits.a = 50;
```

Is this possible in TypeScript, and if so, how?

Comment: No this is not possible right now.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn That's unfortunate to hear, do you know if it is something that exists in other programming languages and/or has a name?

Comment: I don't know about other languages, but alias seems like a good name for the feature.